# Timing in OpenGL program?

Tags: opengl, timing

I have learned enough OpenGL/GLUT (using PyOpenGL) to come up with a simple program that sets up a fragment shader, draws a full screen quad, and produces frames in sync with the display (shadertoy-style). I also to some degree understand the graphics pipeline.

What I don't understand is how the OpenGL program and the graphics pipeline fit together. In particular, in my GLUT display callback,

```
# set uniforms
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)  # draw quad
glutSwapBuffers()
```

I suppose I activate the vertex shader by giving it vertices through `glDrawArrays`, which produces fragments (pixels). But then, does the fragment shader kick in immediately after `glDrawArrays`? There are fragments, so it can do something. On the other hand, it is still possible that there are further draw commands creating further vertices, which can a) produce new fragments and b) overwrite existing fragments.

I profiled the program and found that 99% of the time is spent in `glutSwapBuffers`. That is of course partially due to waiting for the vertical sync, but it stays that way when I use a very demanding fragment shader which significantly reduces the frame rate. That suggests that the fragment shader is only activated somewhere in `glutSwapBuffers`. Is that correct?

I understand that the fragment shader is executed on the GPU, not the CPU, but it still appears that the CPU (program) waits until the GPU (shader) is finished, within `glutSwapBuffers`...

Comment: If your goal is to understand how all those pieces fit together you may want to have a look at Vulkan. In the Vulkan API all those little details about queuing up command buffers, submitting them to the GPU, inserting layout transitions and fences for synchronization and so are exposed to the programmer. In Vulkan a "Hello Triangle" requires about 600 lines of code; in OpenGL it fits into less than 30 lines.

Comment: @datenwolf, yes, I had a quick look at Vulkan and was scared to death. ;) Do you know of some kind of intro-level behind-the-scenes explanation? All I've found googling is either extremely superficial, or focused on how to program (OpenGL). I would like to get at least a basic understanding, but cannot make it a long-term study project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I profiled the program and found that 99% of the time is spent in `glutSwapBuffers`. That is of course partially due to waiting for the vertical sync, but it stays that way when I use a very demanding fragment shader which significantly reduces the frame rate. That suggests that the fragment shader is only activated somewhere in `glutSwapBuffers`. Is 
>   that correct?

No. That logic is completely flawed. The main point here is that the fragment shader *runs on the GPU*, which works totally asynchronous to the CPU. You are not measuring the fragment shader, you are measuring some implicit CPU-GPU-synchronization - it looks like your implementation syncs on the buffer swap (if too many frames are queued up, probably), so all you measure is the time the CPU has to wait for the GPU. And if you increase the GPU workload without significantly increasing the CPU workload, your CPU will just spend more time waiting.

OpenGL itself does not define any of this, so all the details are ultimately completely implementation-specific. It is just guaranteed by the spec that the implementation will behave as if the fragments were generated in the order in which you draw the primitives (e.g. with blending enabled, the actual order becomes relevant evan ion overdraw scenarios). But at what point the fragments will be generated, and which optimizations might happen in-between vertex processing and invocation of your fragment shader, is totally out of your control. GPUs might employ tile-based rasterization schemes, where the actual fragment shading is delayed a bit (if possible) to improve efficiency and avoid overshading.

Note that most GPU drivers work completely asynchronously. When you call a `gl*()` command it returns before it has been processed. It might only be queued up for later processing (e.g. in another driver thread), and will ultimately be transformed in some GPU-specific command buffers which are transferred to the GPU. You might end up with implicit CPU-GPU synchronization (or CPU-CPU with a driver thread), for example, when you read back framebuffer data after a draw call, this will imply that all previous GL commands will be flushed for processing, and the CPU will wait for the processing to be done before retrieving the image data - and that is also what makes such readbacks so slow.

As a consequence, any CPU-side measures of OpenGL code are completely meaningless. You need to measure the timing *on the GPU*, and that's what [Timer Queries](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries) are for.

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks. Please note that my question was not about profiling graphics, it was about how the OpenGL program and the rendering pipeline fit together (temporally). Right now I'm not trying to achieve something, I'm trying to understand something. The profiling was just there to gain some insight, and you may be right, that that was misguided.

Comment: Now, given your answer, what exactly is it that makes my framerate drop when the fragment shader is demanding? If GPU/driver work completely asynchronously, and glutSwapBuffers only synchronizes to vsync, I would expect incompletely rendered frames, not lower frame rate.

Comment: As I wrote, "I understand that the fragment shader is executed on the GPU, not the CPU, but it still appears that the CPU (program) waits until the GPU (shader) is finished, within glutSwapBuffers..."

Comment: As I wrote "you are measuring some implicit CPU-GPU-synchronization - it looks like your implementation syncs on the buffer swap (if too many frames are queued up, probably)"

Comment: There are a couple of different reasons the CPU has to sync to the GPU. At some point, the queue storing all the GL commands will be full, and the CPU has to wait until there is room for new commands again. More likely, there are some resources which require waiting. Usually, the number of frames in the swapchain is limited, so the GPU can not lag behind more than _n_ frames and the driver will stall on the GPU at that point.

Comment: But that does not mean that the synchronization has to happen at the buffer swap - it can happen at any GL call in principle (the first command wirting to the framebuffer after a buffer swap is also a good candidate for implicit syncs)

Comment: If the fragment shader were not finished by the time glutSwapBuffers switches between the buffer the shader was writing to and the buffer that is displayed on screen, that would lead either to incomplete frames (if a new writing buffer is initialized to e.g. black) or to display of frames that belong to different iterations of the shader (the graphics are animated). Neither happens. So as far as I can tell, glutSwapBuffers must in some way wait for the fragment shader. If I'm wrong, please tell me how.

Comment: Well, it _does_ wait for the fragment shader. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: You just wrote "that does not mean that the synchronization has to happen at the buffer swap".

Comment: I wrote that it looks like _your implementation_, in that particulkar scenario, seems to do the sync on the buffer swap. If you run the same code on a different implementation, the synchronization might happen elsewhere (e.g., the mesa linux drivers tend to sync on the next access to the framebuffer after frame queue is full, not the buffer swap).

Comment: Sorry this gets so extended, I'm just trying to understand. By "my implementation" you mean the OpenGL driver and the GLUT library version that I use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193348/discussion-between-derhass-and-a-donda).