# How to write an SDL2 / OpenGL event loop

Tags: python, opengl, sdl-2, pyopengl, pysdl2

I'm writing a real-time interactive graphics application using SDL2 and OpenGL in Python (pysdl2, PyOpenGL). The application continuously produces frames, which may change in response to keyboard / mouse input or based on time.

My main event loop, copied from some obscure source on the web that I can't find again, looks (simplified) like this:

```
event = sdl2.SDL_Event()
running = True
while running:
    # process events
    while sdl2.SDL_PollEvent(ctypes.byref(event)) != 0:
        if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
            running = False
    # render frame
    <some OpenGL commands>
    sdl2.SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window)
    sdl2.SDL_Delay(10)
```

From what I understand, the delay of 10 ms is intended to give the CPU some breathing room, and indeed, when I remove it the CPU usage doubles.

What I don't understand is why it is necessary. The graphics display is double buffered and buffer swaps are synchronized with the vertical retrace (60 Hz = 16 ms). Naively one would expect that if `<some OpenGL commands>` take less than 16 ms, then `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` will introduce a delay anyway, so `SDL_Delay` is not necessary. And if they use more than that, then the program is struggling to keep up with the display framerate, and introducing a delay would hurt.

Now from what I've been told in [response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136639/2056067), the buffer swap and therefore the retrace synchronization doesn't happen when the `SDL_GL_SwapWindow` is executed, but this only puts a "sync & swap" instruction into an OpenGL queue, and this instruction gets executed when everything before has finished. The same holds for `<some OpenGL commands>`. But this instruction queue is finite, and therefore at some point my program, instead of waiting for the retrace, will wait for there to be space in the instruction queue. The end effect should be the same: If one execution of my event loop needs on average less than 16 ms, then the program will on average delay long enough to make it 16 ms per loop execution. So again, why is the explicit delay necessary?

As a second question: Considering the delay might hurt the framerate, is there a better way to let the CPU rest?

Comment: May be initial code intended to limit frame rate to half of vsync, we don't really know (and different monitors have different refresh rate). If you want full monitor refresh rate *and* you have vsync - it isn't needed. Things gets more complicated if vsync is disabled (or badly implemented), but simple constant-value delay isn't a solution here (not to mention delay is not very precise). I don't get the second question though, it is kind of two conflicting points.

Comment: @keltar, thanks and sorry for the late reply. The second question relates to the observation made earlier: "From what I understand, the delay of 10 ms is intended to give the CPU some breathing room, and *indeed, when I remove it the CPU usage doubles.*"

Comment: The program isn't CPU-bound, the CPU is just sending a few OpenGL commands per frame. And the frame rate is controlled by the vsync (to 60 Hz). So, the CPU should be mainly waiting anyway. Still, having `SDL_Delay` reduces reported CPU usage (without reducing frame rate in this case, apparently the CPU needs less than 6 ms per frame). I don't understand it, but something "to give the CPU some breathing room" seems to be needed?

Comment: Maybe `SDL_Delay` has the side effect of signaling the OS scheduler implicitly?

Comment: If you sure you still have 60fps (30 would be too easy for an explaination) then I would've started with systemwide profiler like perf/oprofile on linux or ETW on windows to see where time gets burned. Perhaps dirver sees time to next vsync to be relatively soon and resorts to spinlock instead of OS calls for a delay/reschedule. SDL_Delay is not a spinlock so it does not use CPU, but asks OS to "suspend my process/thread for at least that time" - too unprecise for some tasks.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a reasonable explanation. The driver works in mysterious ways. ;) If you'd make your comments into an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `sdl2.SDL_Delay(10)` because SDL_Delay is timer for SDL2 framework if you use event-loop then it doesn't need with SDL_Delay.

My code for Python 3.10 looks example with KeyPress and Close window by mouse click

```
event = sdl2.SDL_Event()
running = True
while running:
    while sdl2.SDL_PollEvent(ctypes.byref(event)) != 0:
        if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == sdl2.SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if event.key.keysym.sym == sdl2.SDLK_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    ... GL Functions ...

    sdl2.SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window)
```

Remember that event-loop should like other in C/C++,. Java, C# or other programming langauges.

Without event-loop means
you should use `SDL_Delay()` then game window will close automacally.

I hope you understand - I found Python examples but they look like weird and wrong - they write like "Latin".

I would like to improve who understands better like other programming languages.
PS: I will work hard my github with clear examples :)